# Symfony SwiftmailerBundle Configuration Error

Tags: symfony, configuration, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm getting error when

Swiftmailer Configuration in config.yml is,

```
transport: smtp
host:      localhost
username:  %mailer_user%
password:  %mailer_password%
```

And the error is,

Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host 127.0.0.1 [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.#10061]

Can anyone please help me to do configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to include an explanation of this code?

Comment: the same error, mentioned above is giving with this configuration also.